# Send transactions to Ethereum contracts via JSON RPC API

Tags: ethereum

I'm playing around with `geth` and wanted to interacts with contracts through JSON RPC API. However, I'm confused because there is no place for `input` in the `eth.sendTransaction` API.

Per [Ethereum Gitbook](https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/rpc.html#eth_sendtransaction), `eth.sendTransaction` takes in params like this:

```
params: [{
  "from": "0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155",
  "to": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675",
  "gas": "0x76c0", // 30400,
  "gasPrice": "0x9184e72a000", // 10000000000000
  "value": "0x9184e72a", // 2441406250
  "data": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675"
}]
```

All these fields make sense but there is no place to specify the input. Using other tools, such as console and web apps, I can `sendTransaction` and noticed the TX takes a form like this:

```
> eth.getTransactionFromBlock(60)
{
  blockHash: "0xc386191621e45e170d50c1caacc9090b7117e09d0847c46f77f6a3c822ec5580",
  blockNumber: 60,
  from: "0xd9b56ae6e0f7a7e0e0dec74b685b2c7f3f543472",
  gas: 66666,
  gasPrice: 50000000000,
  hash: "0x28aa9e720e11f2f81490b6500a3a56c19ec77b936fc745d16c302387837f324e",
  input: "0xc6888fa10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064",
  nonce: 6,
  to: "0x689495d3e1ff1b955bc4d0bde622bdb34dbb787b",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  value: 0
}
```

Note the there is an **input** field. So is it possible to send transaction via JSON RPC API? If so, which API should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transaction input is represented by `data` param of the `eth_sendTransaction` RPC message.

Comment: I'm glad you answered. Where can I find more information about the encoding of `data`? I searched the gitbook but didn't have a clue.

Comment: That depends what is your contract doing and how it was built. If it comes from solidity or serpent language it will follow Ethereum Contract ABI: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI.